# Windows take divide operator '/' as backslash '\' in Perl command

Tags: windows, perl

I am working with spec benchmarks and using specperl for perl command on windows. I need to do the divide operation in perl command but windows always change `/` operator to `\`. So it cannot be recognized by perl.

I tried multiple writings, but `/` turned to `\`, `//` turned to `\\`, `\/` turned to `\\`, of course `\\` turned to `\\`.

Here is my specperl command:

```
specperl -e "system sprintf qq{start /b /wait /node %x /affinity %x%s %s}, (int($SPECCOPYNUM/40)), (1<<($SPECCOPYNUM%4)), ('0'x($SPECCOPYNUM%40>>2)), q{ %{ENV_PIN_CMD} $command } "
```

Just focus on `int($SPECCOPYNUM/40)`, if I use `int($SPECCOPYNUM*0.025)`, everything works fine. However, this `40` is a variable so I cannot use multiplication to replace it.

Is there no way to do `/` divide operation under this situation?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

It is true that this has nothing to do with windows-perl. 
I tried `R:/ics/itools/efi2_win64/perl/bin/perl.exe -e "system sprintf qq{start /b /wait /node %x /affinity %x%s %s}, (int(1/40)), (1<<(1%4)), '', q{ ls } "` directly in windows command shell and it works fine.
When I put this in spec config file, it is changed, `/` becomes `\`, but I found the option `/b /wait /node` keeps the `/`. Sad. I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Neither Windows nor Perl does that. Are you perhaps involving a non-Windows build of Perl (cygwin, MSYS, etc?) Please provide more information about your environment (shell) and about your build of Perl.

Comment: The only 'specperl' I can find mentioned in a search is apparently a 90's era perl code generator for the spectcl gui builder, but the link to the project is dead...

Comment: I am also using perl on windows, and `/` works as expected. So, windows/perl is not responsible for it

Comment: Sure, that is annoying and the above comments do not provide a solution... the workaround would be not to divide by `$divider`, but make it multiply by the `$reciprocal` of that `$divider` like `my $reciprocal = (1/$divider);` just like you did in your own comment, where it works fine, as you said

Comment: @vanHoesel I cannot do like this because my `$SPECCOPYNUM` may not be divisible like `28`.

Comment: @ikegami It is the config file required by running SPEC benchmarks. https://www.spec.org/cpu2017/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you say doesn't add up. There's no difference between the earlier `/` and the latter `/` as they are all in the same argument. I suspect you misdiagnosed the problem.

There's nothing in the [docs](https://www.spec.org/cpu2017/Docs/config.html) about any of this.

But if there's indeed a problem with `/`, you can work around it as follows:

```
int(eval(qq{$SPECCOPYNUM\x2F40}))     # int($SPECCOPYNUM/40)
```

Comment: I tried this. The log shows `int(eval("$SPECCOPYNUM\x2F40"))` cannot be recognized. Also ,I tried `R:/ics/itools/efi2_win64/perl/bin/perl.exe -e "system sprintf qq{start /b /wait /node %x /affinity %x%s %s}, int(eval("1\x2F40")) , (1<<(1%4)), '', q{ ls } "` in command shell. It shows error: `Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "2F40"
        (Missing operator before F40?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "2F40"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: You'll have to use something other than double quotes because you used those fot he entire argument.

Comment: I use `int(eval('$SPECCOPYNUM/\x2F40'))` , it works!!  Thanks so much! This really helps me.

Comment: That can't possibly be true

Comment: And again, that's a hack that's only necessary because of false and incomplete information available to me

Comment: You are right. `int(eval('$SPECCOPYNUM/\x2F40'))` will not report error but it will not use 80 cores as I expect. `int(eval(qq{$SPECCOPYNUM\x2F40})) ` is the correct one.